# Issue with looping through an array and setting value with custom cell in UITableView iOS Swift

Tags: arrays, uitableview, loops, swift

I have a custom cell in my UITableView that contains a button. This button acts as a check box and has it's own class that swaps between two images. Anyway...What I'm trying to do is set the check box state to "checked" for certain cells containing a certain attribute. This code below gives me the expected result, but I do not want to hard-code these values with if-statements. I would like to instead loop though my array of "currentItemCondiment" to get the same result.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell: customCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ItemCell" ,forIndexPath: indexPath) as customCell

    let menuItem = self.condiments[indexPath.row]

    if (currentItemCondiments[0] == menuItem.title) {
        cell.customCellCheckbox.setSelected()
    }
    else if (currentItemCondiments[1] == menuItem.title) {
        cell.customCellCheckbox.setSelected()
    }

    else {
        cell.customCellCheckbox.setUnSelected() 
    }
    return cell
}
```

I want to write a loop like the one below here to get the same result as above, but this code will only select the checked box at its last index.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell: customCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ItemCell" ,forIndexPath: indexPath) as customCell

    let menuItem = self.condiments[indexPath.row]

    for item in currentItemCondiments {
        if (item == menuItem.title) {
            cell.customCellCheckbox.setSelected()
        }
        else {
            cell.customCellCheckbox.setUnSelected()
        }

    return cell
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 'break' when checkbox is selected.

```
for item in currentItemCondiments {
    if (item == menuItem.title) {
        cell.customCellCheckbox.setSelected()
        break
    }
    else {
        cell.customCellCheckbox.setUnSelected()
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I wish I had the reputation to up-vote this...Thank you so much.